# Windows 10 PIN - RDP

Tags: windows, windows-10, pin

I have a user with a Windows 10 machine - they have linked it to their MS account, and they use a PIN to access the machine.  We have a few people who share the machine so the users know what the PIN is.

I am trying to connect using RDP however all I can login with is the username and password.  I would like to use the PIN as the user does not want to share their MS password for obvious reasons.

The office is a small office, no Active Directory etc.

Al

Answer (score 3):

As obvious as it may seem to not use a password, a PIN is highly vulnerable to hackers, since it is only numbers. It is for this security reason that Microsoft blocks using PIN for RDP. A few suggestions:

1) DONT use a Microsoft account on a shared PC.

2) Use alternative remote software or VNC to connect which directly mirror the screen. This will let you use the pin.  Be aware that VNC is not encrypted by default either, and is potentially susceptible to attack.